# How to fix "Symbol's function definition is void: org-babel-get-header"

Tags: org-mode, debugging, bash, prelude, babel

How do you trouble shoot this? (trying to run a sh block async)

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh                                                                                                   
/tmp/7.sh                                                                                                        
#+END_SRC
```

Then I do

```
C-c C-c
```

I get

```
Symbol's function definition is void: org-babel-get-header
```

My setup

prelude emacs25 org installed

```
;; my ~/prelude/personal/personal.el
(prelude-require-package 'ob-async)                                                                              
(require 'ob-async)   
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)                                                                            

(org-babel-do-load-languages                                                                                     
 'org-babel-load-languages                                                                                       
 '(                                                                                                              
   (sh . t)                                                                                                      
   (ruby . t)                                                                                                    
   ))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove cause of an error in loading .emacs: Symbol's function definition is void: defvar-local](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28028/how-to-remove-cause-of-an-error-in-loading-emacs-symbols-function-definition)

Comment: There are (today) 34 questions with a match for `function definition is void`: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22function+definition+is+void%22

The error always means the same thing, in the immediate sense, though the proper remedy can be different in different cases (e.g. trying to use a variable as a function, package not loaded yet, wrong Emacs version). The most common cause is not first loading the needed library. 

It would be great if someone *carefully* consolidated most or all of those questions into a new, generic, community question with a good answer.

Answer (score 12):

According to https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-11/msg00425.html `ob-sh` was renamed `ob-shell` in org 8.2 ... and I cite from there:

> org-babel-get-header was removed in 0d000f5 (babel: small change in
>   API., 2015-10-29), but the old ob-sh.el is still trying to call it.

That means you should replace `(sh . t)` by `(shell . t)` in your call of `org-babel-do-load-languages`. **And don't forget to re-start emacs afterwards!** ;-)

EDIT: You don't need to to change the source language of your source code blocks from `sh` to `shell`. It is only important to call `org-babel-shell-initialize`.

The source code languages that are supported by `ob-shell` are defined in the option `org-babel-shell-names` (which can be customized).

The default value of `org-babel-shell-names` is:

`'("sh" "bash" "csh" "ash" "dash" "ksh" "mksh" "posh")`

From these names `org-babel-execute:...` functions are generated by `org-babel-shell-initialize`.

Comment: what about the code block header, use sh or shell

Comment: You can use either, but there is a slight different between them. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/what-is-the-difference-between-sh-and-shell-for-org-babel